# Join and sum multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Table TB1:

```
| PaymentID | CashAmount |
--------------------------
|     P1    |       3,000|
|     P2    |       5,000|
|     P3    |       8,000|
```

Table TB2:

```
|ChequeID| PaymentID |ChequeAmount|
-----------------------------------
|   C1   |     P2    |      10,000|
|   C2   |     P1    |      15,000|
|   C3   |     P1    |       2,000|
```

Table TB3:

```
|TransferID| PaymentID |TransferAmount|
---------------------------------------
|    T1    |     P2    |        20,000|
|    T2    |     P2    |        20,000|
|    T3    |     P1    |         3,000|
```

Expected Result

```
| PaymentID | CashAmount |ChequeAmount|TransferAmount|
------------------------------------------------------
|     P1    |       3,000|      17,000|         3,000|
|     P2    |       5,000|      10,000|        40,000|
|     P3    |       8,000|        NULL|          NULL|
```

How to write a query JOIN and SUM all these tables together?
I tried writing simple join query but the result was wrong.

Example of incorrect query:

```
SELECT    
    TB1.PaymentID, TB1.CashAmount,
    SUM(TB2.ChequeAmount) AS ChequeAmount, 
    SUM(TB3.TransferAmount) AS TransferAmount
FROM        
    TB1
LEFT JOIN 
   TB2 ON TB1.PaymentID = TB2.PaymentID
LEFT JOIN 
   TB3 ON TB1.PaymentID = TB3.PaymentID
GROUP BY    
   TB1.PaymentID, TB1.CashAmount
```

Incorrect result:

```
| PaymentID | CashAmount | ChequeAmount | TransferAmount |
----------------------------------------------------------
|     P1    |      3,000 |      17,000  |         6,000  |
|     P2    |      5,000 |      20,000  |        40,000  |
|     P3    |      8,000 |        NULL  |          NULL  |
```

Comment: What result does this query produce?

Comment: @Mureinik, I have added the incorrect result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is you're joining the tables that have multiple rows with the same id and it multiplies the numbers. You'll need to do the sum first and then join the data. Assuming the data can be missing from any of the tables, you'll also need to use full outer join. If TB1 has the row always, then left outer join is enough.

This is how you can do it:

```
SELECT      
  coalesce(TB1.PaymentID,TB2.PaymentID,TB3.PaymentID), 
  TB1.CashAmount, TB2.ChequeAmount, TB3.TransferAmount
from (
  select PaymentID, SUM(CashAmount) AS CashAmount
  from TB1 group by PaymentID
) TB1
full outer join (
  select PaymentID, SUM(ChequeAmount) AS ChequeAmount
  from TB2 group by PaymentID
) TB2 on TB1.PaymentID = TB2.PaymentID
full outer join (
  select PaymentID, SUM(TransferAmount) AS TransferAmount
  from TB3 group by PaymentID
) TB3 on isnull(TB1.PaymentID, TB2.PaymentID) = TB3.PaymentID
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e3f9/1)

Comment: Yes TB1 is like a main table and must always have a record in order to TB2 and TB3 to exist. In this case, am I safe to use LEFT OUTER JOIN for both joins? Thank!

Answer (score 2):

I would eliminate the duplicates in the minor tables first, then (left) join and sum with the major table, like this

```
SELECT      
  TB1.PaymentID, 
  TB1.CashAmount, 
  Sum(TB2.ChequeAmount) as ChequeAmount, 
  Sum(TB3.TransferAmount) as TranAmt
from TB1 
left join (
  select PaymentID, SUM(ChequeAmount) AS ChequeAmount
  from TB2 group by PaymentID
) TB2 on TB1.PaymentID = TB2.PaymentID
left join (
  select PaymentID, SUM(TB3.TransferAmount) AS TransferAmount
  from TB3 group by PaymentID
) TB3 on isnull(TB1.PaymentID, TB2.PaymentID) = TB3.PaymentID
group by
tb1.PaymentId, tb1.CashAmount
```

Comment: is 'Sum(TB2.ChequeAmount) as ChequeAmount, 
  Sum(TB3.TransferAmount) as TranAmt' in the first select statement redundant?

Comment: If paymentId/cashamount in TB1 is unique then both the sum and group by of the first select are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH  t2
        AS (
             SELECT [PaymentId], SUM([ChequeAmount]) AS ChequeAmount
             FROM   TB2
             GROUP BY [PaymentId]
           ),
      t3
        AS (
             SELECT [PaymentId], SUM([TransferAmount]) AS TransferAmount
             FROM   TB3
             GROUP BY [PaymentId]
           )
  SELECT  t.PaymentId, SUM(CashAmount) AS CashAmount,
          SUM(t2.[ChequeAmount]) AS [ChequeAmount],
          SUM(t3.[TransferAmount]) AS [TransferAmount]
  FROM    TB1 AS [t]
  LEFT JOIN [t2] ON [t2].[PaymentId] = [t].[PaymentId]
  LEFT JOIN [t3] ON [t3].[PaymentId] = [t].[PaymentId]
  GROUP BY [t].[PaymentId];
```